# CRUD POST issues

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, rest

I am building out the front end of my MEAN project. My Server side works fine, so if I send a post request to local host, with firstName, lastName, email and password, I get a success response.
[image]

Here is my function in Angular:

```
  signUp(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this._http
      .post('/signup', JSON.stringify({ user }), { headers })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ user }));
        return res.success;
      });
  }
```

Unfortunately this just returns a `success: false` parameter. An example test spat the console log out as:

> {"user":{"firstName":"fghnjmkcvbnm","lastName":"dfghjk","email":"dfghj@ghnjm.com","password":"fghjk12345456"}}

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: *" this isn't working"* is a completely inadequate problem statement. tells us next to nothing about what does or doesn't happen. Also doesn't make sense using `map` chained to an http request

Comment: @charlietfl well the API just returns a `success: false` response, not sure why it is failing?

Comment: Start by inspecting actual request in browser dev tools network to see if what is sent is what is expected and any additional clues . Need to isolate where problem is...could be server or client side

Comment: Did you try submitting an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request instead, which is what you're using in the postman screenshot you've provided? Perhaps your server isn't set up to parse/accept `application/json` requests.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the content type.

I would refactor your code this way:

```
signUp(user) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let user = new URLSearchParams();
  user.set('email', 'some email');
  user.set('password', 'some password');
  user.set('firstName', 'first name');
  user.set('lastName', 'last name');

  return this._http
    .post('/signup', user.toString(), { headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map((res) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify({ user }));
      return res.success;
    });
}
```